# Creating a database under a different owner

Tags: postgresql, security, permissions

I'm trying to set up a role in Postgres which can
a) Create a new Role
b) Create a new Database
c) Make that new Role the owner of the database
d) Have no other rights (as far as is possible!)

I have tried this:

```
sc_1=# CREATE ROLE tenant_admin CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
CREATE ROLE
sc_1=# CREATE ROLE user1 IN ROLE tenant_admin LOGIN NOINHERIT ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'xyz';
CREATE ROLE
sc_1=#
```

Followed by (in another session)

```
tahaan@Komputer:~/projects/acme-project$ psql -U user1 -h localhost -d postgres
Password for user user1: 
psql (9.3.6)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> SET ROLE tenant_admin;
SET                                                                                                                     
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE "Tenant1" TEMPLATE "tenant_template";
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=> CREATE ROLE "owner1";
CREATE ROLE
postgres=> ALTER DATABASE "Tenant1" OWNER TO "owner1";
ERROR:  must be member of role "owner1"
postgres=>
```

Background:  The requirement is to have an automated function that can setup separate databases in a multi-tenant system.  My hope is that this function can be performed by a role that does not have too much rights.

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution involving a few extra steps.  The "tenant_admin" role is still created the same way, but it is now used as follow:

```
postgres=> SET ROLE tenant_admin;
SET                                                                                                                     
postgres=> CREATE ROLE "owner3";
CREATE ROLE
postgres=> GRANT "owner3" TO "tenant_admin";
GRANT ROLE
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE "Tenant3" OWNER "owner3";
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=> REVOKE "owner3" from "tenant_admin";
REVOKE ROLE
```

Comment: Why are you using double quotes?

Comment: Things in double-quotes are inspected and used to reference to other things.  Single quotes are for human-readable string values that are not de-referenced by Postgres.

Comment: But why use quotes at all?  E.g. why `"owner3"` not `owner3`?

Comment: At the time I wrote this I was busy automating the process.  Many of the names were derived from things entered by users of the apps.  So just generally a good idea to quote all of them.

Answer (score 8):

Had this problem with RDS when trying to create new DB.

## To solve it:

Login as superuser

```
psql --host=xxxxxxx --port=5432 --username=SUPERUSER_NAME --password --dbname=postgres
```

Create the User

```
CREATE USER newuser WITH CREATEDB PASSWORD 'password';
```

Logout

```
\q
```

Login as `newuser`

```
psql --host=xxxxxxx --port=5432 --username=newuser --password --dbname=postgres
```

Create your DB

```
CREATE DATABASE ....
```

Answer (score 2):

To Creating a user in postgres, Creating a database under a different user in postgres, Creating a schema under a different database with new user in postgres,

Login as Postgres-user

```
psql --host=xxxxxxx --port=5432 --username=postgres --password
```

create a Database:

```
postgres=>CREATE DATABASE newdb;
```

Create New-User:

```
postgres=>CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD 'uSeRi04o8';
```

Grant permission:

```
postgres=>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "newdb" to user1;
```

Login to New-Database with new user:

```
postgres=> \connect newdb user1
...
You are now connected to database "newdb" as user "user1".
newdb=>
```

To create schema with new user "user1" in newdb:

```
newdb=> CREATE SCHEMA s1;
```

To list all the schema in postgres from specific db :

```
SELECT * from information_schema.schemata;
```